# Error al intentar compilar KB en Genexus17 para Apple

Tags: genexus

Tengo una KB parametrizada para que genere el código fuente para Apple.
Logré compilarla con Excution Type = "Simulator(Mac)" y luego al llevarla a la MACbook a traves del XCODE pude hacer un "run" y levantó el Emulador de Iphone X corriendo la app desarrollada en Genexus.

Ahora lo que estoy haciendo es, cambié la propiedad Excution Type a "iOS Device(Mac)" y al compilar (F5) me arroja el error:

**error: Development Team ID property is required to execute in the device
error: error: Signing for "VitaD_PNPrincipal" requires a development team.
Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
...
Failed: iOS Compilation**

Cuando me paro en el PanelSD principal y tipeo el nombre del "Development Team ID" me lo borra.
(el Development Team ID en el AppStore existe. Está dado de alta e incluso desde el XCode se ve en la lista desplegable de Team dentro de "Signing & Capabilities")

La pregunta es: Cómo debo cargar correctamente la propiedad Development Team ID (iOS) en Genexus para que no me de el error mencionado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estas Ulises? El development team id es un alfanumerico que deberia verse algo asi:

```
LK3R5D2FCC
```

Capaz estas poniendo el Team Name (que es el que se ve en tu foto de xcode), y ese al no ser un valor valido para la propiedad en GeneXus, te lo borra.

Para saber cual es tu Team Id, tenes que entrar en "developers.apple.com" y bajo "Membership" de tu cuenta te lo dice (al loguearte con tu usuario) .

Para mas info, podes ver este link que lo explica:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30100,Development+Team+ID+property

Comment: mucha gracias. Era eso. Con la cuenta de Desarrollador Apple loguerse en:

https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership

Ahi ir a "Membership" donde estan los datos de Team ID (es un alfanumerico)  y Name (es un string)